# I want to add the values of editText boxes over several layouts to post them to an editText box on a layout called results

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my formula:

```
(R.id.dch135-(R.id.drg59*.0752)-(R.id.drg6*.061)-(R.id.drg11*.0412)-(R.id.dplenum*.0802)-(R.id.s2way*4.5)-(R.id.s3way*6.9)-(R.id.sbal35*4.5)-(R.id.sunbal70*8.8)-(R.id.s4way*8.8)-(R.id.s8way*13)-(R.id.sdc6th*3.3)-(R.id.sdc9th*2.7)-(R.id.sdc12th*2)-(R.id.sdc6tp*6)-(R.id.sdc9tp*9)-(R.id.sdc12tp*12)-(R.id.samp*14.5)
```

I have editText boxes on several layouts. I want to run the formula above on them and get a result to display on a editText box on another layout called results.

I have tried using the getText but all I get back is "Cannot invoke setText(String) on the primitive type int".

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: The problem (probably) isn't in the formula you show, since it doesn't have a `setText` call. Post the code that triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you say `(R.id.drg59*.0752)` you mean "get the value from the EditText with  ID `drg59` and multiply if by 0.0752. However, what that means in Java is "multiply the value R.id.drg59 (an integer value defined in R.java, not whatever is currently in your edittext) by 0.0752".

You need to *parse* each of the EditText values to a number (a float, presumably) and THEN multiply it by the 0.0752. For example:

```
 EditText drg59Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.drg59);
 float drg59Value = Float.parseFloat(drg59Text.getText());
 float result = drg59Value * 0.0752;
```

So on and so forth.

Also, when setting the text value you need to convert the value to a string, the easiest way is generally to just append you value to an empty string:

```
 EditText resultText = ...
 resultText.setText("" + result); //where "result" is a float value
```